# Can not receive chat in recent chat in Chat Application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

I am creating Chat Application and I am using android studio and firebase realtime database and I was trying to chat between two users...but while sender sends message to the receiver then the sender can see username message label in "Recent chat" but at receiver side, it can not receive sender name in "Recent Chat", All chat will be store on firebase realtime database but it can not display message at receiver side.

```
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    String userid;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            intent=getIntent();
            userid=intent.getStringExtra("userid");
            firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    notify = true;
                    String  msg=text_send.getText().toString();
                    if(!msg.equals(""))
                    {
                        sendMessage(firebaseUser.getUid(),userid, msg);
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this,"Can't Send Empty Messaage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    text_send.setText("");
                }
            });

    }

    // sendMessage Method

    private  void sendMessage (final String sender, final String receiver, String message)
        {
            DatabaseReference databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("sender", sender);
            hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
            hashMap.put("message", message);
            hashMap.put("isseen",false);

            databaseReference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);

//This portion is not working


            final DatabaseReference chatref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist")
                    .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                    .child(userid);

            chatref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        chatref.child("id").setValue(userid);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

//ChatFragment

public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private List<User> musers;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private List<Chatlist> userslist;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        userslist=new ArrayList<>();
        firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userslist.clear();;
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Chatlist chatlist = snapshot.getValue(Chatlist.class);
                    userslist.add(chatlist);
                }
                chatList();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void chatList() {

        musers=new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                musers.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user=snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    for(Chatlist chatlist:userslist){
                        if(user.getId().equals(chatlist.getId())){
                            musers.add(user);
                        }
                    }

                }
                userAdapter=new UserAdapter(getContext(), musers,true);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: the question is too broad. if you are able to isolate a specific portion of code that is  not working, that would be more useful for us to help.

Comment: sure please look